# C# WPF - Accessing a variable from another page in a button click event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So, what I am trying to accomplish is create a Media application that goes out and grabs files to display on the application and if the user wants, also view the item. Right now, I am dealing with one category of files, which is videos (Movies). What I want to do is when a user clicks on an item, I will go and see which file they clicked since the way I list it is through data binding, and grab the path from that item which I have defined. The problem is, is that after the button takes you to the page with a media player, I am unable to access the variable I created to store the item path, nor the item that was clicked. I am not very experienced with C#, and I was wondering how I could access the MovieItem that corresponds with the item that the user clicked on.

Here is the click event for the button that the item falls under on my SharedMovies page...

```
public void GetFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button OpenFile = (Button)sender;
        if (OpenFile.DataContext is MovieItem)
        {
            MovieItem FileInfo = (MovieItem)OpenFile.DataContext;
            string MoviePath = FileInfo.filePathExt;
            string ItemPath = FileInfo.filePath;

            if (MoviePath == ".mp4" || MoviePath == ".AVI")
            {
                NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
                nav.Navigate(new Uri("VideoPlayer.xaml"));                   
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Sorry, this media is not supported by our player. Please select another item, or change the media so it is in a supported format.", "Unsupported Format", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }                   
    }
}
```

This is the logic behind the list of movies for the SharedMovies page MovieItem object that gets created for each file in the movie list:

```
public SharedMovies()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ///Declares variables and lists for files and icons
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\READYSHARE\USB_Storage\Movies", "*",
                                     SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        List<string> fileExt = new List<string>();
        List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
        List<BitmapSource> iconList = new List<BitmapSource>();
        ///Sets filename of each file without the extension/full path, and gets the icons from each file
        foreach (string File in filePaths)
        {
            string Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(File);
            string Movie = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File);
            BitmapSource icon = ShellFile.FromFilePath(File).Thumbnail.BitmapSource;
            iconList.Add(icon);
            fileList.Add(Movie);
            fileExt.Add(Extension);


        }
        ///Setting counter for both icon and file count (Compatibility) and create new item list that extends from MovieItem function - same with MovieIcon
        List<MovieItem> items = new List<MovieItem>();
        int MovieIconCount = -1;
        int MovieCount = 0;
        //makes count and adds item to
        foreach (string Movie in fileList)
        {
            MovieIconCount = MovieIconCount + 1;
            MovieCount = MovieCount + 1;

            items.Add(new MovieItem() { FileIcon = iconList[MovieIconCount], FileName = Movie, FileNumber = MovieCount, filePath = filePaths[MovieCount - 1], filePathExt = fileExt[MovieCount - 1]});
        }

        MovieGrid.ItemsSource = items;
    }
    public class MovieItem
    {
        public BitmapSource FileIcon { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public int FileNumber { get; set; }
        public string filePath { get; set; }
        public string filePathExt { get; set; }
    }
```

Finally here is the binding code for the list on the xaml page (SharedMovies.xaml) for SharedMovies:

```
<ItemsControl Name="MovieGrid" Margin="20">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button x:Name="MovieFile" Margin="15,1" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="GetFile_Click" >
                    <StackPanel Name="MovieFileBlock">
                        <Image Name="MovieIcon" Source="{Binding FileIcon}" OpacityMask="Black" Width="30" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

And for the page I am trying to pass it to, VideoPlayer, I have a media element that has a binding for the source of the media, which is what I will set the variable to (Here is the code so far with just the binding I have it to:

```
private class MediaItem
    {
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
    }
```

Thank you guys ahead of time!

To put it in less lengthy terms, I just need a way to get the path of the item the user chose from the VideoPlayer page.

Answer (score 0):

A day of working it out, and I found an answer to my problem. In order to pass the file path so that the media element could play the video selected is to create a Application property which can be used Globally. First, on my button event (the button that is generated for every file), since I can retrieve the filepath from there, and that is when I will most likely need to set the property, I made a application property like so,

```
            MovieItem FileInfo = (MovieItem)OpenFile.DataContext;
            string MoviePath = FileInfo.filePathExt;
            string ItemPath = FileInfo.filePath;

            if (MoviePath == ".mp4" || MoviePath == ".AVI")
            {
                ///Created new app property here:
                Application.Current.Properties["FilePath"] = ItemPath;
                this.NavigationService.Navigate(new VideoPlayer());                 
            }
```

and instead of using my old navigation statement, I just made a new instance of the page using a much simpler navigation technique. Then I created an override method (VideoPlayer page) that when the page is initialized, that the Player (Name of the media element) has a source that is equal to the file path of the item that was clicked on. Of course, I had to do a conversion to string and then make a new Uri to set it equal to the property. Otherwise you will get a error saying that you can't convert to a string from an object (Just because of path, normal string is fine):

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);
        MediaElement Video = (MediaElement)Player;
        Video.Source = new Uri(Application.Current.Properties["FilePath"].ToString());
    }
```

Hopefully that helped anyone who had trouble passing data through to other pages!